# Fullcalendar drop event VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I have a problem where I can't get the data from my draggable object to show.

```
  setupDraggable() {
  new Draggable(document.getElementById("planned-tasks"), {
    itemSelector: ".fc-event",
    eventData: function(eventEl,date, jsEvent, ui, resourceId) {
    let newEvent = {
        title: eventEl.innerText
      };
      console.log(newEvent);
     return newEvent;
    }
  }
  );
},
```

How can I get the callback to newEvent.date?
Do I have to create a new async method to get event data from draggable object?

Comment: _"How can I get the callback to newEvent.date? _"...sorry I have no idea what you are asking. This question doesn't have any obvious meaning in relation to fullcalendar. Can you clarify please?

Comment: P.S. also a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem would help a lot.

Comment: @ADyson It's hard to formualte the question properly for me, sorry. https://codepen.io/bstensberg/pen/PoqKbBe that's all the code I have.
When I drop an event I need it to send the date information so I can pass it through my API. However, I don't really understand how to handle the "drop" in fullcalendar

Comment: where is your code to create and dislpay the calendar? That's where you have to handle the "drop" callback.

Comment: @ADyson `<Fullcalendar>` in the html?

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking of Angular instead of vue, where it can be defined in the code. Any you would need to add `@drop="someFunction"` into the list of settings inside the `<FullCalendar` element, and then define `someFunction` in your methods list (as per the example at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/vue (under the "emitted events" heading). Or if you want to get the actual event data from the Draggable, you actually need `@eventReceive` instead (see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventReceive)

Comment: @ADyson yes i figured that out right after I wrote the second comment! Thank you :) You got me on the right path, I was just overthinking this way too much